# Agregar valores no R

Tags: r

Ao tentar agregar valores por pessoa, recebo o erro abaixo dizendo que a função `sum`não funciona para fatores, no entanto, meu vetor é numérico e mesmo usando uma função para garantir isso, continuo a receber o erro!

```
url <- "https://raw.githack.com/fsbmat/StackOverflow/master/DiariasT.csv"
Diaria2 <- data.table::fread(url, dec = ",",colClasses = c("factor", "factor",  "numeric","numeric", "numeric"))
Diaria2$VALOR_DIA <- as.numeric(as.character(Diaria2$VALOR_DIA))
agg = aggregate(Diaria2,
                  by = list(Diaria2$VALOR_DIA),
                  FUN = sum)
```

---

```
Error in Summary.factor(18L, na.rm = FALSE) : 
  ‘sum’ not meaningful for factors
```

Comment: Quer agregar por `NOME_ORG_SOL`, por `NOME` ou por ambos?

Comment: Quero agregar por NOME.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O código da pergunta tem a variável a agregar, `VALOR_DIA`,  onde deveria estar a variável de agregação. E falta a variável de agregação, que não pode ser a base inteira, um objeto de classe `"data.frame"`.

**Uma maneira de agregar.**

Esta maneira usa uma `formula` para agregar o lado esquerdo pelas variáveis do lado direito (só uma).

```
agg <- aggregate(VALOR_DIA ~ NOME, data = Diaria2, FUN = sum)
```

**Outra maneira.**

Esta maneira é a maneira usada na pergunta mas de forma correta.

```
agg2 <- aggregate(Diaria2$VALOR_DIA,
                 by = list(Diaria2$NOME),
                 FUN = sum)
```

Comparando os resultados vê-se que a única diferença é nos nomes das colunas dos dois resultados, os valores das somas são iguais.
Pesoalmente, prefiro o interface de fórmula por ser intuitivo e também por produzir resultados com nomes iguais aos das variáveis usadas.

```
all.equal(agg, agg2)
#[1] "Names: 2 string mismatches"
names(agg)
#[1] "NOME"      "VALOR_DIA"
names(agg2)
#[1] "Group.1" "x"
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Tentei de várias formas e não percebi o erro simples que estava cometendo!